# Python: Stopping the program with a print statement

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, return, break

I'm trying to finish off my program here, while everything is in place but for the def endapp() function, I have no idea how to make it print "Goodbye" to mark the end of the program without having the menu() function or any other function like login() looping back again. Everything else is working the way it is, but I have no clue how I can end the program with just a print message. I just need the program to stop outputting anything after printing "Goodbye", where it reaches a dead end, not by using sys.exit() to exit the whole application. Note: The functions viewapp(), addapp(), summary() are all going to loop back to logged(), I haven't added code for that yet, while endapp() should have no loops at all and should end with "Goodbye" and no other function should be looping back to ask for input again. Help would be appreciated, with code example.

```
vault = {}


def menu(): 
    mode = input("""Hello {}, below are the modes that you can choose from:\n
    ##########################################################################
    a) Login with username and password
    b) Register as a new user
    To select a mode, enter the corresponding letter of the mode below
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """.format(name)).strip()
    return mode

def login():
    if len(vault) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
        print("Welcome to the login console")
        while True:
            username = input ("Enter Username: ") 
            if username == "":
                print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            password = input ("Enter Password: ") 
            if password == "":
                print("Password Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            try:
                if vault[username] == password:
                    print("Username matches!")
                    print("Password matches!")
                    logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
            except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
                print("The entered username or password is not found!")

    else:
        print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")

def register(): #example where the username is appended. Same applies for the password
    print("Please create a username and password into the password vault.\n")

    while True:
        validname = True
        while validname:
            username = input("Please enter a username you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your username must be at least 3 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not username.isalnum():
                print("Your username cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(username) < 3:
                print("Your username must be at least 3 characters long \n")
            elif len(username) > 30:
                print("Your username cannot be over 30 characters \n")
            else:
                validname = False 
        validpass = True

        while validpass:
            password = input("Please enter a password you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your password must be at least 8 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not password.isalnum():
                print("Your password cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(password) < 8:
                print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long \n")
            elif len(password) > 20:
                print("Your password cannot be over 20 characters long \n")
            else:
                validpass = False #The validpass has to be True to stay in the function, otherwise if it is false, it will execute another action, in this case the password is appended.
        vault[username] = password
        validinput = True
        while validinput:
            exit = input("\nEnter 'end' to exit or any key to continue to add more username and passwords:\n> ")
            if exit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
                return
            else:
                validinput = False
                register()
        return register

#LOGGED ONTO THE PASSWORD AND WEBSITE APP ADDING CONSOLE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def logged():
    print("You are logged in!\n")
    keeplooping = True
    while keeplooping:
        modea = input("""Below are the options you can choose:
        ##########################################################################\n
        1) Viewapp
        2) Addapp
        3) Summary
        4) Exit
        ##########################################################################\n
        > """).strip()

        if modea == "1":
            viewapp()

        elif modea == "2":
            addapp()

        elif modea == "3":
            summary()

        elif modea == "4":
            keeplooping = False
            print("Goodbye")
        else:
            print("That was not a valid option, please try again: ")
            validintro = False 
    return modea 


def viewapp():
    print("*Insert viewapp*")

def addapp(): 
    print("*Insert addapp*")       

def summary():
    print("*Insert summary*")

#Main routine
print("Welcome to the password vault program")
print("In this program you will be able to store your usernames and passwords in password vaults and view them later on.\n")
validintro = False
while not validintro:
    name = input("Hello user, what is your name?: ")
    if len(name) < 1:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
    elif len(name) > 30:
        print("Please enter a name no more than 30 characters: ")
    else:
        validintro = True
        print("Welcome to the password vault program {}.".format(name))

#The main program to run in a while loop for the program to keep on going back to the menu part of the program for more input till the user wants the program to stop
validintro = False 
while not validintro: 
        chosen_option = menu() #a custom variable is created that puts the menu function into the while loop
        validintro = False

        if chosen_option in ["a", "A"]:
            login()

        elif chosen_option in ["b", "B"]:
            register()

        else:
            print("""That was not a valid option, please try again:\n """)
            validintro = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can suggest u to do is that: 
1st - In the logged() in function: if the user choose

`elif modea == '4'
    keeplooping = False
    print('Goodbye')
    return keeplooping`

2nd - In the login() function: instead of while True. You can do is that

```
def login():
if len(vault) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
    print("Welcome to the login console")
    state = True
    while state:
        username = input ("Enter Username: ")
        if username == "":
            print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
            continue
        password = input ("Enter Password: ")
        if password == "":
            print("Password Not entered, try again!")
            continue
        try:
            if vault[username] == password:
                print("Username matches!")
                print("Password matches!")
                state = logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
                return state #return the state of user option (True/False)
        except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
            print("The entered username or password is not found!")

else:
    print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")
```

3rd - In the main program validintro should be changed accordingly

```
validintro = False
while not validintro:
    chosen_option = menu() #a custom variable is created that puts the menu function into the while loop
    validintro = False

    if chosen_option in ["a", "A"]:
        validintro = not login()

    elif chosen_option in ["b", "B"]:
        register()

    else:
        print("""That was not a valid option, please try again:\n """)
        validintro = False
```

it's quite a tip trick but it must work